# What's the difference between CancellationTokenSource constructor delay parameter and CancelAfter Method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, c#-6.0

Given these two approaches

```cs
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
```

```cs
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
```

Is there any real difference in behaviour?

The only slight of information is on [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.cancelafter?view=net-6.0) but it's not clear since quoting

> Subsequent calls to CancelAfter will reset the delay for this CancellationTokenSource, if it has not been canceled already.

So I guess it resets it but does it have any other action regardles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to the source](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/mscorlib/system/threading/CancellationTokenSource.cs#L84), nothing. They both assign to `m_timer`